# Why my text fold into 4 lines?

Tags: html, css

Code:

```css
#a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}

#b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    test test test test<span id="b">xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx</span>
</div>
```

The result is like that:

```
          test test test test

                                          xxxx 
                                          xxxx 
                                          xxxx 
                                          xxxx
```

You can see my "xxxx" texts fold into 4 lines.

But what I want is:

```
          test test test test

                                          xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

So my question:

1. Why my text fold into 4 lines instead of 1 line?
2. How to achieve the result I wanted?

---

EDIT:

As @Manish Dalal posted, it's quite a strange behavior:

> Is there any CSS rule applied on div or width of any of the parent is limited?
>
> If I copy only this code (as is) on an HTML page, I can see what you wish to achieve. So I assume that some parent control that have position relative and have limited width (by itself or due to its parents') and hence have limited the width of the div. (As by default a div will take all the horizontal spacing.)

Comment: Provide some width to span...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any CSS rule applied on `div` or width of any of the parent is limited?

If I copy only this code (as is) on an HTML page, I can see what you wish to achieve. So I assume that some parent control that have position `relative` and have limited width (by itself or due to its parents') and hence have limited the width of the `div`. (As by default a `div` will take all the horizontal spacing.)

Comment: If you can please post the complete HTML & CSS or HTML & CSS up till the parent for which `position: relative` is set.

Comment: I know set that div with `position: relative` works, but I just want to know why ...

Comment: I do not want you to set the `position:relative` for that div with id="a"

Comment: What I am asking is.... see that if any of its parent tag (in which this div is contained) have any width assigned? This could be its immediate parent or parent of the parent and so on till body tag

Comment: It will be easy for me to assist you if you can share the complete page HTML

Comment: The code in question's snippet is all the code I have... I'm learning CSS by reading specification(CSS 2.1) thoroughly and I'm just testing every feature mentioned by specification...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122181/discussion-between-manish-dalal-and-sayakiss).

Comment: check that: http://pastebin.com/LeWjeMaF. It's example from  https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details . I just modified a little bit.

Comment: After going through various posts regarding `position:absolute` I also learned that when `position:absolute` is applied, the elements do not behave as block level elements (which is the default with `div`). Hence, as soon as `position:absolute` is applied to the `div`, it takes the minimum required to display all its content. Now, as `span` is inside the `div`, and it is not a block level element, so it displays its content but try not to go beyond the right edge of its parent `div`; hence it splits its content.

Comment: I said 'try' (in above comment) because if you put continuous text (like a large word or words concatenated by underscore) then they will go beyond the right edge of its parent `div`. You can check all this by setting borders of `div` and `span`.

Comment: To make `div` take all the space till the right edge of its parent (or browser window), set `right: 0px` for the div (with `position:absolute`). `width:100%` will take the div outside the right edge of its parent (as it is displaced from left side)

Comment: Really thanks for detailed explanation. Could you please post the url of the article you read to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

For absolute positioning(`position: absolute`) width is needed, as `width` is not specified the text is being wrapped.

**Here are few solutions:**

1. Change `position:absolute` to `position: relative` for `#b`. Most suitable.
2. Add `width` to `#b`.
3. Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `#b` for avoiding text wrapping. This will make longer text appear in a single line with scrollbar. Not preferable.

Check below demo.

```css
#a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
#b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  test test test test<span id="b">xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain a little about why text wraps here?

Comment: And what if the text is too long? This doesn't works, because the text will ever see on a single line, however the length of that text

Comment: but why is it not displayed as it is required. Because by default div takes all the horizontal space, but in this case its width is limited.

Comment: @ManishDalal : It's because of `position: absolute` in `#a` the parent div

Comment: @Pugazh Ok, this is better answer than your first try. My upvote ;)

Comment: `absolute` positioning takes the element out of the document flow for within the next parent which has `relative` positioning. What you are telling is `fixed` positioning. 
Kindly check https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/ and http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Then why the page at http://mtsecureserver.com/so.html is displayed as the OP wanted it to? Feel free to check the page source.

Answer (score 3):

change absolute to relative in the b case

Comment: You can explain better this case, in my opinion the valid solution, and not `white-space`

Comment: but why is it not displayed as it is required. Because by default div takes all the horizontal space, but in this case its width is limited.

Comment: well, if both things they all have to have (left: 200px; top: 100px;) property which cant happen as they are several strings, so either ad a width to the whole line or mark them as relative to the other one. At least that what my understanding is, but I'm just a beginner myself so I'm not really sure if this is the right way to explain.

Comment: This is not the right answer. There is problem in one of the parent tag's width. The OP should check that

Comment: Check and please explain why the page at http://mtsecureserver.com/so.html is displayed as the OP wanted it to? Feel free to check the page source.

Comment: @ Manish Dalal because it has the white-space: nowrap; but it looks the same if you change from absolute to relative to me. Again as i mentioned above: but I'm just a beginner myself so I'm not really sure if this is the right way to explain. So care to explain this yourself? Im guessing your way to do it is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed;`

```css
#b {
 position: fixed;
 left: 200px;
 top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: but why is it not displayed as it is required. Because by default div takes all the horizontal space, but in this case its width is limited.

Comment: Absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal document flow, and therefore it does not interact with the other elements.

Comment: `absolute` positioning takes the element out of the document flow for within the next parent which has `relative` positioning. What you are telling is `fixed` positioning.

Comment: Kindly review https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: and http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Then why the page at http://mtsecureserver.com/so.html is displayed as the OP wanted it to? Feel free to check the page source.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
#b {
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  test test test test<span id="b">xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx</span>
</div>
```

Comment: but why is it not displayed as it is required. Because by default div takes all the horizontal space, but in this case its width is limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it without `nowrap` you need to define a width for `#b` then use width and display property to define css.

```css
#a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}

#b {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    test test test test<span id="b">xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx</span>
</div>
```

Comment: but why is it not displayed as it is required. Because by default div takes all the horizontal space, but in this case its width is limited.

Comment: it is because #b is absolute positioning. In absolute positioning it not getting 100% width for #b.

Comment: `absolute` positioning takes the element out of the document flow for within the next parent which has `relative` positioning. What you are telling is `fixed` positioning. 
Kindly check https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/ and http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Then why the page at http://mtsecureserver.com/so.html is displayed as the OP wanted it to? Feel free to check the page source.

Answer (score 0):

Why use absolute positioning for such alignment. just alter a bit the markup, example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/yrtfay0k/1/

Instead of absolute positioning you can just float the item.

```
float:right
```

But it really depends on what you really want to achieve and be more specific, there are many options to solve it.